# stationary sets

Tags: set-theory

Let $\{S_i: i < \omega\}$ be a strictly decreasing sequence of stationary subsets of $\omega_1$,
is the intersection of all $S_i$'s stationary?

Comment: Before people vote to reopen: This is an elementary question, not appropriate for the site.

Comment: I completely agree with Andres. This question belongs to http://math.stackexchange.com and not here.

Comment: I just want to know the answer to this question, I am not sure about the meaning of "elementary" posed by Andres Caicedo, is it a question too easy to answer?

Comment: @sonicyouth: Elementary in the sense that MO is dealing with research level questions, and this is most certainly not such question. This is an advanced undergrad (or grad) level course material. As I suggested in my other comment, math.stackexchange.com is a far more suitable location for this question.

Comment: http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/847/stationary-sets/

Comment: It's been asked and answered over at math.SE http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/14747/is-the-intersection-of-a-decreasing-sequence-of-countably-many-stationary-subsets

Answer (score 3):

I am answering this as CW, or else it will keep popping up periodically.

Suppose $\{S_n\mid n\lt\omega\}$ is a decreasing collection of stationary subsets of $\omega_1$. If their intersection is non-stationary, then it must be the case that some $S_n\setminus S_{n+1}$ is stationary, or else $S=\bigcap_n S_n$ is stationary, and in fact $S_0\setminus S$ is non-stationary (i.e., modulo the non-stationary ideal, $S$ and $S_0$ are the same).

The same observation in fact gives us that infinitely often $S_n\setminus S_{n+1}$ must be stationary. By passing to a subsequence, we may as well assume that this holds for all $n$. But then, we may also assume that $\bigcap_nS_n$ is empty, as we can remove $S$ from each $S_n$ and preserve their stationarity.

Hence, if a sequence is as asked, we obtain that, letting $T_n=S_n\setminus S_{n+1}$, the sequence of sets $T_n$ is a pairwise disjoint sequence of stationary sets. Conversely, from any such sequence we obtain a decreasing sequence of stationary sets $S_n$ with empty intersection, by letting $S_n=\bigcup_{m\ge n}T_m$.

What this says is that the question is equivalent to whether there is a sequence of pairwise disjoint stationary sets, and this is well-known to be true.

In the interest of being self-contained, let me add that the usual proof that there are such sequences is due to Ulam, using what we now call a *Ulam matrix*: Fix injections $f_\alpha:\alpha\to\omega$ for all $\alpha\lt\omega_1$, and set, for $\alpha\lt\omega_1$ and $n\lt\omega$, $$S_{\alpha,n}=\{\beta\lt\omega_1\mid \alpha<\beta\mbox{ and }f_\beta(\alpha)=n\}.$$ Then, for any fixed $\alpha$, $$\bigcup_n S_{\alpha,n}=\omega_1\setminus(\alpha+1),$$ so there is some $n_\alpha$ such that $S_{\alpha,n_\alpha}$ is stationary.

But then it follows that for some $m$, $n_\alpha=m$ for $\omega_1$ many $\alpha$. Note now that for any $n$, $$S_{\alpha,n}\cap S_{\alpha',n}=\emptyset$$ whenever $\alpha\ne\alpha'$, and we conclude that, considering $n=m$, there are in fact $\omega_1$ pairwise disjoint stationary sets.

An easy elaboration of this argument shows that any stationary set can be split into $\omega_1$ pairwise disjoint stationary subsets. The same argument shows that any stationary subset of $\kappa^+$ can be split into $\kappa^+$ pairwise disjoint stationary subsets, for any infinite $\kappa$, and (considering the ideal of measure zero sets rather than the non-stationary ideal) that no successor cardinal is real-valued measurable.

That stationary subsets of $\lambda$ can be split into $\lambda$ pairwise disjoint stationary subsets actually holds for all regular (uncountable) cardinals $\lambda$, not just successors (but a different argument is needed, of course). This was proved by Solovay.